# Backpack crud field that displays an included filtered table

Tags: laravel-backpack

I need to make a new type of field, let's call it **included_table**. If in Model employees I have a field of type select2 from model Departments, in Departments, I want to have a field of type included_table which displays the table of the employees from that department, in the same way as the crud does.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Or what would be the best way to start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do it. You'd have to code it yourself. You can start from the `table` field type, put it won't get you very far.

That's because it's a lot more complicated that it looks at first glance. Keep in mind that Backpack create/update forms work with refresh; if you put a table inside one of them, the expected behaviour might be to only "save" the information when you click the final "save" button; but you probably can't do that for the nested entity, because you'd be saving it with AJAX. Plus, you need to build that entire AJAX functionality yourself, including validation. It's not at all more difficult than using plain old Laravel - it's exactly the same. But Backpack won't help very much in this regard.

That being said, you'd probably be better off just putting a button in the list view for each Department, to go edit its employees. That's a lot easier to do, if you [follow the nested resources tutorial](https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not want the full crud functionality for the included table. The main concern is the display of that table as a field (not column), nothing gets actually saved for this field here. There will be an add record button and edit record buttons for the included records, but they will take the user to the normal crud for that form.

Also an (ajax) refresh button for the (display only) table would be needed to update it once the cross record is added or edited.

Thank you.

Comment: I understand. Still no ready-built solution, sorry, you'll have to create it yourself.